# Cannot show more than one error Message. Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm creating a login page using Java servlets and JSPs. I'm just posting my doPost method and the validateData method. My concern is I want to output more than two error messages on the page. The errorMessageList is the array that is responsible for holding the String messages. Initially I was trying out with inputting invalid first name and last name by entering numbers in both fields. The corresponding error messages gets stored in the array but is not displayed. Only the first error Message gets displayed which is
Error: Invalid First Name. Cannot be empty / contain numbers but the next error 
Error: Invalid Last Name. Cannot be empty / contain numbers is not displayed even though the errorMessageList already has it. I'm also providing my JSP. Some help will  be greatly appreciated!

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // We are creating all the parameters on the browsers and sending them to the server 
    String uName = req.getParameter("userName");
    String pWord = req.getParameter("password");
    String cPass = req.getParameter("confirmPassword");
    String fName = req.getParameter("firstName");
    String lName = req.getParameter("lastName");
    String gender = req.getParameter("gender");

    Client client = new Client();
    client.setClientName(uName);
    client.setPassword(pWord);
    client.setConfirmPassword(cPass);
    client.setFirstName(fName);
    client.setLastName(lName);
    client.setGender(gender);


    List<String> errorMessageList = validateServlet(client);
    boolean isEmpty = errorMessageList.isEmpty(); 
    System.out.println("the errorMessageList is empty:"+isEmpty);

    if(errorMessageList.size()==0){//Successful registration

        ClientDao clientDao = new ClientDaoImpl();
        clientDao.createClient(client);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/registrationSuccess.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    }

    // Error in the submission data. Therefore show registration page. 
    for(int i = 0; i < errorMessageList.size(); i++){
    req.setAttribute("errorMessages", errorMessageList.get(i));
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/registration.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }


    super.doPost(req, resp);
}

public List<String> validateServlet(Client client){

    List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();


    if(client.getClientName() == null || client.getClientName().trim().length() == 0){// Null or Empty

        errorMessages.add("Error: Your forgot to type in User Name");

    }

    if(client.getFirstName() == null || client.getFirstName().trim().length() == 0 || client.getFirstName().matches(NUMBERS_PATTERN)){

        errorMessages.add("Error: Invalid First Name. Cannot be empty / contain numbers");

    }
    if(client.getLastName() == null || client.getLastName().trim().length() == 0 || client.getLastName().matches(NUMBERS_PATTERN)){

        errorMessages.add("Error: Invalid Last Name. Cannot be empty / contain numbers");

    }else if(!client.getClientName().matches(EMAIL_PATTERN)){

        errorMessages.add("Error: Invalid user. User Name should be user@domain.com");

    }else if(client.getPassword() == null || client.getPassword().trim().length() == 0){// Null or Empty

        errorMessages.add("Error: Your forgot to type in Password");

    }else if(client.getConfirmPassword() == null || client.getConfirmPassword().trim().length() == 0){// Null or Empty

        errorMessages.add("Error: Your forgot to confirm password");

    }else if(!client.getPassword().equals(client.getConfirmPassword())){

        errorMessages.add("Error: Password and confirm password do not match..");

    }       
    return errorMessages;
}


 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Client Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#EEFFEE" align="center">
<%

   String eMessage = (String)request.getAttribute("errorMessages");
%>
<form action = "/iservlet-webapp/registration" method = "post">
     <%if(eMessage != null){ %>
        <div style = "color:#CC3300; align:center">
            <%=eMessage%>
        </div>  
     <%} %>


<font face="Arial" color="green">User Registration Page</font>
<hr>
<br>
<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor= "green" bgcolor="CCFF99">
    <tr>
        <td>User Name</td>
        <td><input type ="text" name ="userName" maxlength = "50"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type ="password" name ="password" maxlength = "15"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td><input type ="password" name ="confirmPassword" maxlength = "45"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type ="text" name ="firstName" maxlength = "45"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><input type ="text" name ="lastName" maxlength = "45"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><input type ="text" name ="gender" maxlength = "1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type = "submit" name ="Login"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 // Error in the submission data. Therefore show registration page. 
    for(int i = 0; i < errorMessageList.size(); i++){
    req.setAttribute("errorMessages", errorMessageList.get(i));
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/registration.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
```

With above piece of code you are only setting `1 error` which is at `0th` index of List , because you are invoking `forward()` method on every iteration .

Instead you should add the complete `errorList` as attribute :

```
req.setAttribute("errorMessages", errorMessageList);
req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/registration.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Now just iterate the list in JSP .

---

**Update**

*How to iterate list in JSP ?*

```
<c:forEach items="${errorMessages}" var="error">
    <h2>${error}</h2>
</c:forEach>
```

For using `<c:forEach>` you need to add `jstl.jar` in your class path and add the below line in your jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: I thought of that too. But it throws ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object. And then I don't know what else I need to fix afterwards.. Any thoughts?

Comment: you are converting `list` into `String` in your JSP that is why you are getting this exception , just check the updated answer on how to iterate the list in jsp